# How to perform a join and aggregate count in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class Unit (models.Model):
    Unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Hull_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Parent_unit = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True)
    Class = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    Member = models.ManyToManyField(Member, through='MemberUnit')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Unit_name

class MemberUnit(models.Model):
    Member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    Unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    Position = models.ForeignKey(ClassPosition)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Unit.Unit_name + " " + 
                self.Position.unit_position.Position_name + " ( " + 
                self.Member.first_name + " " + self.Member.last_name + " )"
```

I am new to Django (sort of).  Querying is where I am lacking.
What I need is a aggregate count of Unit_names.

To that end, I require a query as part of my view to provide a Unit_Name and it's count.
Any Assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need the count of Unit objects with the same unit_name? How is the MemberUnit class needed? Please explain more about what you need.

Comment: Yes.  Each Member is assigned a Unit.  MemberUnit is the Many-to-Many bridge between Unit and Member.  To that end, Each Unit/Member Combo will be registered in MemberUnit.  My thought was to count the number of Units and provide a grouping (ie. Select Unit, count(unit) from MemberUnit group by Unit).  However, I don't want the Unit.id, I want Unit.Unit_name.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
from django.db.models import Count
MemberUnit.objects.values('Unit__Unit_name').annotate(c=Count('Unit'))
```

You can try this in Django's shell:

```
manage.py shell
```

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/)